# Product export download is not working in magento 2.1.15

Tags: magento2, product, export

I am using AWS server. I tried to export the product from the back-end. But while downloading it showing `Failed- Server Unreachable` in chrome browser. Is that related to owner permission issue? Because in inside the `var` folder that exported CSV is present but while downloading it's not working. If I hit direct URL with that CSV file means it's working fine. Please tell me any idea to fix this issue...

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7317

Comment: Thanks, @Venkat. I'll refer the link. I think the issue with AWS server, for other servers it's working fine.

Comment: Sounds good. May I know what issue did you faced in aws server that will help others

Comment: Debugging in progress, will let you know after the completion

Answer (score 0):

please override Download.php file from the vendor.

**1. Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\File\Download.php**

add changes to in.

```
 public function execute()
    {
        if (empty($fileName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filename'))) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Please provide export file
name'));
        }
        try {
            $path = 'export/' . $fileName;
            $directory =
$this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
            if ($directory->isFile($path)) {
                return $this->fileFactory->create(
                    *$fileName,*
                    $directory->readFile($path),
                    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                    'application/octet-stream'
                );
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException | \Exception $exception) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('There are no export file with
such name %1', $fileName));
        }
    }
```

Hopefully, it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Added *$fileName,*
$directory->readFile($path),
DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
'application/octet-stream'
And it working likes a charm. Thankyou

Comment: This is not an answer per se. The solution was presented previously.